# WCF service via channel factory returns non-correct values

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, channelfactory

I am trying to call a method located in a remote wcf service using Channel Factory. It is the first time for me to use channel factory, but it returns non-correct values of the properties of the object.
Below I will present the code:

IVrindassDigitalService.cs:

```
public interface IVrindassDigitalService
{
        Vrindassinfo GetVrindassStatusAndDate();
}
```

VrindassDigitalService.cs:

```
public class VrindassDigitalService: IVrindassDigitalService
    {
        public Vrindassinfo GetVrindassStatusAndDate()
        {
            
            BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            Vrindassinfo result = new Vrindassinfo();

            try 
            {
                EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(“http://svc-server/OnlineDataStore.svc”);

                ChannelFactory<IVrindassDigitalChannel> myChannelFactory =
                new ChannelFactory<IVrindassDigitalChannel>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

                // Create a channel
                IVrindassDigitalChannel wcfClient = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
                result = wcfClient.GetVrindassStatusAndDate();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return result;            
        }           
    }
```

Vrindassinfo class:

```
public partial class Vrindassinfo
    {
        public System.DateTime VrindassDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime VrindassDateTime { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
    }
```

WSDL Snippets:

```
<wsdl:portType name="Utility">
<wsdl:operation name="GetVrindassStatusAndDate">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/Utility/GetVrindassStatusAndDate" message="tns:Utility_GetVrindassStatusAndDate_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/Utility/GetVrindassStatusAndDateResponse" message="tns:Utility_GetVrindassStatusAndDate_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>

…..
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Utility" type="tns:Utility">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetVrindassStatusAndDate">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Utility/GetVrindassStatusAndDate" style="document"/>
………….
```

Call method:

```
//get Vrindass date
Vrindassinfo VrindassInfo = _VrindassDigitalService.GetVrindassStatusAndDate();
```

The problem is that the values of the fields (VrindassDate and VrindassDateTime) of the Vrindassinfo object come as 01/01/0001, which are not the real values that should be returned by the web service.The web service must return the current date. I have been trying to solve it as a problem for several hours, but I don't know where exactly the problem is.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean January 1st of year 1 CE is returned or that the format is not what you expect?

Comment: When you say that there is no real value that the web service should return, what should it return? Is it a regular date like DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")?

Comment: @NineBerry the format is correct, the purpose of Web service is to return just current date

Comment: Several things to check: Set a breakpoint or add output within your catch block. You will miss any exceptions currently. If there is an exception, it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue?